# How can I get the variance of weighted linear regression below?

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, weighted-regression

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$My weighted linear regression turned out to be as follows:

$\vec{m} = \left(A^TW^TWA\right)^{-1}A^T\left(W^TW\right)\vec{y}$

$\vec{m} $ is a vector of coefficient

$A$ is a design matrix such as $A = \begin{bmatrix} \dots & x_1^T & \dots \\ & \vdots & \\ \dots & x_n^T & \dots\end{bmatrix}$.

$W$ is a weight matrix consisting of $ w_i = \dfrac{1}{\hat{s}_i}$ on the diagonal positions such as $W = \begin{bmatrix}w_1 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\ 0 & w_2 & \dots  \\ \vdots \\ & & & w_n\end{bmatrix}$

I tried to derive the variance from the above weighted linear regression but I am stuck in the middle of the matrix calculation as below:

$\Var(\hat{\beta}_{WLS}|A) = (A^TW^TWA)^{-1}A^T(W^TW)\Var(\vec{y}|A)W^TWA(A^TW^TWA)^{-1}$

How can I proceed further?

Comment: Go back to the beginning and rewrite $WA$ as, say, $X$ and $Wy$ as, say, $z$.  What you get should look so familiar that you can take it from there.

Comment: @user122358   It's not usual to call your $W$ a weight. What is normally referred to as a weight is (in your notation) $W^TW$ (which is often written as $W$ in typical weighted regression treatments). For example if you wanted to replace two identical observations with a single observation given additional weight, it would be natural to say it should have weight $2$ (akin to the weighted mean $\sum_i w_i y_i/\sum_i w_i$). Your $W$ doesn't do that but your $W^TW$ does.